# Change the highlight background thickness of a Canvas?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas, tkinter-canvas

I know how to change the color of the highlightbackground of a Canvas using tkinter, but I am not sure how to change the thickness of it. When I try to change the `baz['highlightbackgroundthickness']` or the `baz['highlightbackgroundwidth']`, it errors out. Please help, thanks!

Sample code:

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Canvas

foo = Tk()
bar = Frame(foo, bg = "white")
bar.grid()
baz = Canvas(bar, width=50, height=50, bg = 'blanched almond')
baz.grid(row=0, column=0)
baz['highlightbackground'] = 'blue' #I know how to change this
baz['highlightbackgroundthickness'] = 2 #Error
baz['highlightbackgroundwidth'] = 2 #Error
#enter code for changing highlight background thickness here
```

Comment: Did you try `highlightthickness` option?

Comment: [Here](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/canvas.html) is a lit of options for a canvas. Possibly you are looking for ```highlightthickness```

Comment: ProTip: You can see all the options of a widget by printing it's keys. `print(tk.Canvas().keys())`. It's more convenient than searching docs. Especially if you already know what all the various options do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @acw1668 and @nikost's comments, it turns out the option to change that is `highlightthickness`. See below code!

```
from tkinter import Tk, Frame, Canvas

foo = Tk()
bar = Frame(foo, bg = "white")
bar.grid()
baz = Canvas(bar, width=50, height=50, bg = 'blanched almond')
baz.grid(row=0, column=0)
baz['highlightbackground'] = 'blue'
baz['highlightthickness'] = 2 #change the highlight thickness!
```

Thanks to @OneMadGypsy, I learned that you can print out the keys of a Canvas to find the one you want doing this:

```
from tkinter import Canvas

print(Canvas.keys())
```